# PrintWriter throwing FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, processing, printwriter

I am writing a code that outputs to a text file using the PrintWriter class. However, when I try to initialize a new PrintWriter it throws a FileNotFound exception.

Here are two versions of my code that both don't work, writer is initialized in the global variable as a PrintWriter.

```
File file = new File(fileName);
writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
writer.println("N: " + N);
writer.println("E: " + E);
writer.println("D: " + D);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
writer.println("N: " + N);
writer.println("E: " + E);
writer.println("D: " + D);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Here is a list of the imports I'm using, am I possibly missing one?

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.math.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
```

Comment: Is `fileName` an absolute path? Btw, in your first example did you mean to pass in file: `PrintWriter(file)`?

Comment: Post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) here. You'll get the faster unswer or you'll faster find it yourself.

Comment: PrintWriter throws FNFE if it can't open file for writing.

Comment: I have also tried using file.createNewFile() but it throws and IOException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the code seems to be correct and working fine for me. Ensure that the path is given properly. If in case no path given ensure to call the method [createNewFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()) to create the file from abstract filename as below

```
File file = new File("test1.txt");
file.createNewFile();

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("test1.txt");
writer.println("N: ");
writer.println("E: ");
writer.println("D: ");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

You can also use file object along with PrintWriter.

Comment: This method throws an IOException of the create file line and still throws the FileNotFoundException. Am I missing any imports?

Comment: Can you post the line at which error comes. Can you also post your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(fileName);
writer = new PrintWriter(file);
```

This should work.

Comment: This method still throws the FileNotFoundException for me